# Runtime-ошибка в реализации алгоритмической задачи

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Компилятор ошибок не выдает. Не знаю, как решить по-другому.
Вводится последовательность из n вещественных чисел.
Определить количество элементов в наиболее длинной подпоследовательности
подряд идущих чисел, представляющих собой степени тройки.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int n, len = 0, ans = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        bool err = (x != 0);
        while (x > 0)
        {
            if (x == 1) 
                break;

            if (x / 3 != 0)
            {
                err = false;
                break;
            }
            x /= 3;
        }
        if (err) 
        {
            len++;
            if (len > ans)
                ans = len;
        }
        else
            len = 0;
    }

    cout << ans;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А степени только положительные?

Comment: Разделите ваш код на функции, а? Вам нужно по крайней мере (1) ввод массива, (2) тест на степень тройки, (3) проверка массива. А то у вас спагетти-код получается.

Так вам будет легче понять, какая часть кода работает не так, как вы ожидали.

Answer (score 3):

1. Чтобы понять, является ли число степенью тройки, нужно его прологарифмировать по основанию 3. Если полученный логарифм не имеет дробной части, то число является степенью трех, в противном случае не является. Кстати, вариант с логарифмом избавляет от необходимости заботиться об отрицательных показателях степени (1/3, 1/9, 1/27 и тд). В C++ для вычисления логарифмов есть функция log (для нее нужно подключить заголовок math.h). Однако тут есть небольшая проблема - она вычисляет только натуральные логарифмы. Однако, как вам должно (а может и не должно) быть известно еще со школы, что логарифм X по основанию Y равен логарифму X по основанию Z деленному на логарифм Y по основанию Z. Поэтому Нужный вам логарифм можно вычислить, поделив натуральный логарифм вашего числа на натуральный логарифм трех. При этом нужно также помнить и о погрешности, которая неизбежно присутствует при сохранении десятичных дробей в памяти, поэтому сравнивать полученный логарифм нужно не с нулем, а с неким достаточно малым числом.
2. Как сделать обход по массиву рассказывать, честно говоря, лень, вот реализация на C#:

   ```
       var array = new [] { 3, 3, 27, 2 };
       var threes = new List<bool>();

       foreach (var a in array)
           threes.Add(IsThreeDegree(a));

       int max = 0, currentCounter = 0;
       foreach (var t in threes)
       {
           if (t)
               currentCounter++;
           else
           {
               if (currentCounter > max)
                   max = currentCounter;
               currentCounter = 0;
           }
       }
       if (currentCounter > max)
           max = currentCounter;
   ```

Comment: Однако, какой вы собираетесь брать epsilon для тестирования на степень тройки? Обратите внимание на вот это: http://ideone.com/JEeiNI

Comment: >Я бы написал как-то так

я бы тоже написал, но раз уж я дал решение на шарпе, то хотелось избежать линка и прочих исключительно-шарповских вкусностей, написав пример относительно близко к C++, чтобы не искушать юный разум всяческой ересью) Вряд ли было бы честно забивать ТСу голову лямбдами, если в его случае речь идет об алгоритмах

Comment: @DreamChild: в прошлом коде была ошибка, сорри. Вот правильный код:

    var threes = array.Select(IsThreeDegree);
    int runningSum = 0;
    var lengths = threes.Select(curr => curr ? ++runningSum : (runningSum = 0));
    var max = lengths.Max();

Но вы правы, в целях обучения лучше без лямбд и LINQ.

В продолжение обсуждения, мне кажется, техника LINQ как раз хорошо применима к алгоритмам: оно даёт фундаментальные `map` и `reduce` (под именами `Select` и `Aggregate`). Но конечно новичку лучше бы сначала с императивным подходом разобраться.

Comment: >Однако, какой вы собираетесь брать epsilon для тестирования на степень тройки? 

собственно, вот почему я вспомнил о погрешности - скажем, если взять число 1/9, то очевидно, что его логарифмом по трем будет -2. Однако, если же записывать 1/9 в десятичной форме, то у нас будет бесконечная периодическая дробь 0.11111... (ни или 0.(1) с точки зрения математики). Так вот в таком случае логарифм для 0.11111111111 будет равен -2.0000000000091, что несколько отличается от двух. В общем-то мелочь, тем не менее, об эпсилонах забывать не следует хотя бы на будущее

Comment: @DreamChild: это да. Проблема с кодом в http://ideone.com/JEeiNI такая: у двух чисел, одно из которых является степенью тройки, а другое — нет, вычисления дают одинаковый логарифм. То есть получается, что на основе логарифма выяснить, является ли число степенью тройки, в принципе невозможно.

Comment: ах вот оно что. Ну тогда можно в дополнение к  использованию логарифмов посоветовать предварительно проверять на отсутствие дробной части - для чисел > 1

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить является ли число степенью тройки StackOverflow [предлагает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804311/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-power-of-3) два любопытных решения: одно, предложенное [starblue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49246/starblue)  более очевидно математически, другое авторства [Ray Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199245/ray-burns)  более эффективно. Эти решения не рассматривают случай отрицательных степеней.